# Passing Datetime value from a C# Script component to SSIS Datetime variable

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I have the following code:

```
Dt1 = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["User::FileTrxDT"].Value;
Dt1= Dt1.AddDays(1);
Dts.Variables["User::FileTrxDT"].Value = (DateTime) Dt1.ToString();
```

It gives a exception at run time. I can get the date in but can't send it back.

Any direction/help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: To verify, the SSIS Variable, `@[User::FileTrxDT]` is of type DateTime

Comment: Yes the variable User::FileTrxDT is a SSIS DateTime